# Can I remove AdMob ads:testDevices

Tags: android, android-emulator, admob

I used below code to test my app on the emulator.

```
<com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       ads:adUnitId="MY_AD_UNIT_ID"
                       ads:adSize="BANNER"
                       ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"
                       ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```

When I'm ready to publish my app on google play, should I remove the `ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID"` portion in above code or can I keep that portion with rest of code?

Comment: i left test_emulator in mine and im making money, idk arout testdeviceid

Comment: Of curse you should remove the ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, TEST_DEVICE_ID".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you refer to the [Admobs Best Practise Guide](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/best-practices#testmode), it states this:

> Remember to turn the testing flag off before deploying your app if you
>   want to receive real ads.

I suspect the intention behind this is to protect the device ID from falling into wrong hands in case the app was to be reverse engineered. *That is of course speculation on my part.*

However, I don't see why leaving behind just this `TEST_EMULATOR` would cause a problem. But feel free to remove that if you so desire.

Alternatively, you can also turn off testing for all devices from your Admobs console -> *Manage Settings* (for the specific app) -> *App settings* tab and selecting this option: *Disable test mode for all requests*.

This will, however, still not deal with hard-coded device ID's in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

It won't effect anything. And your app will show ads for all devices except for those listed as test devices.

However, in general its a good practice to turn off ads before deploying your app.

**"Remember to turn the testing flag off before deploying your app if you want to receive real ads." , says [documentation](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/best-practices)**